# how to convert a Laravel Web App to Mobile App

Tags: php, laravel, react-native, mobile

i am curious, is there a way to convert it from **laravel** based website to **react-native** mobil app. I can't give any code examples to the community. Because i don't have any one. I have been researching this for a while. I could not reach any solution.

Actually react-native doesn't important. My main question is how to convert

`"laravel => mobile app"`

Must be an easiest solution for this. No one wants to write from the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create your mobile application separately and create API for your webapp for the communication between mobile app and Web app. Ofcourse there are some nonrecomended methods everywhere but if you need a good mobile application that works perfectly. There is no shortcut you need to do this.

You can do it as a native application or a hybrid one

Comment: I agree to this answer, Shortcuts are dangerous

Comment: That was clear. Thanks for helping.